# Adding a struct into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

So lets say I have a struct like this:

```
struct example_structure 
{
int thing_one;
int thing_two;
};
```

I also have an empty array which I am trying to fill with these structs. I am trying to add them as follows, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
array[i].thing_one = x;
array[i].thing_two = y;
```

Instead of this is there a way to declare a variable of type example_structure and then add that to the array?

Comment: What are the types for `x` and `y`?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem to be working" mean? `example_structure example; ...; array[i] = example;` is perfectly valid but clearly you have a deeper issue here.

Comment: by it doesnt seem to be working, I mean that the structures are not all being added to the array. I thought this section of my code may be the issue since I'm unfamiliar with using structs

Comment: What do you mean "added to the array"? Did you preallocate a large block of data for `array` ahead of time? Are you trying to dynamically increase the size of it and, if so, have you done that already prior to your `array[i]` accesses but not shown it here? Does `i` have a sane value? Is `array` actually an array or are you using some other container type? Need more information. Show a full example. Note the guesswork being done in the answers below. This guessing should not be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Use vectors. They can expand as needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    struct example_structure 
    {
        int thing_one;
        int thing_two;
    };

    std::vector<example_structure> data;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        data.push_back({i, i * 2});
    }

    for (const auto& x : data)
    {
        std::cout << x.thing_one << " " << x.thing_two << "\n";
    }
}
```

Live example:
http://ideone.com/k56tcQ

Comment: If you do it this way, just be sure to update your code if you change the order of members in the `struct`. You might want to add a comment to the `struct` indicating that the member order should not be changed, especially if both members are the same type. C++ has a habit of providing lots of opportunities to blow semantics out of the water. It might be worth mentioning for completeness that you can also declare an `example_structure example;` and initialize it first before `.push_back(example)`.

Comment: How about `emplace_back`? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can write simply

```
array[i] = { x, y };
```

Or you can have a separate variable of the type of the structure. For example

```
struct example_structure obj = { x, y };
array[i] = obj;
```

Comment: That wont' work. The OP says, "I also have an empty array which I am trying to fill with these structs.".

Comment: If you do it this way, just be sure to update your code if you change the order of members in the `struct`. You might want to add a comment to the `struct` indicating that the order should not be changed. C++ has a habit of providing lots of opportunities to blow semantics out of the water.

Comment: @R Sahu  I have not understood why it wiill not work.

Comment: It's not clear if the array has a certain size but is uninitialized, or he has an empty data structure.